# why does my code echo my post variables but still give me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() warnings?

Tags: php

I get two warnings Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() but I still retrieve my expected post variables.  Where am I going wrong? It says the warning is in regard to line 7, which in this case is the line that begins;  foreach($value as $k => $v)

```
    <!------------- quote.php ----------------->

<body>
What services are you interested in? <br/><br/>

<form name="input" action="quote2.php" method="post">

<?php

$services = array('Tree Felling', 'Height Reduction', 'Crown Thinning', 'Deadwooding/Ivy Removal', 'Stump Grinding', 'Other');
 foreach ($services as $option) { ?>

 <input id="<?= $option ?>" type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="<?= $option ?>" />
 <label for="<?= $option ?>"><?= $option ?></label>
 <br />
<? } 
?>
<br/>

<input name="name"  type="text" />NAME</br>
<input name="place" type="text"/>TOWN</br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>


<!------------   quote2.php  -------------->



<?php 

echo '<h3>SERVICES REQUIRED</h3>';

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

  foreach($value as $k => $v)
  {  
  echo '<p>'.$v.'</p>';
  }

} 

echo "<hr /><h3>DETAILS</h3>";
echo $name = $_POST['name'];
echo "</br>";
echo $place = $_POST['place'];
echo "<hr/>"

 ?>
```

Comment: Unless your form has elements that have `[]` in their name attribute. You can double foreach the `$_POST` array, which by default is just a 1 dimensional array. EDIT: Aaand ninja'd

Comment: Not related to your problem, but ID's cannot contain spaces.

Comment: Argh. Brain. Shutting Down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there is a very real possibility that not all of the items in your $_POST array will have **values** of type array; which you are assuming according to the code in *quote2.php*

A simple **is_array()** check will ensure that only arrays get iterated over in the foreach, here is the edited file contents:

```
<!------------   quote2.php  -------------->



    <?php 

    echo '<h3>SERVICES REQUIRED</h3>';

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            foreach($value as $k => $v)
            {  
                echo '<p>'.$v.'</p>';
            }
        }
    } 

    echo "<hr /><h3>DETAILS</h3>";
    echo $name = $_POST['name'];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $place = $_POST['place'];
    echo "<hr/>"

     ?>
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

A number of the form controls do not have names that end in `[]` and so are not arrays.

You can't loop over a string.

You should pull out each value of the submitted data individually and only loop over services.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your foreach loop in an if statement to check the array is an array. For example:

```
if (is_array($services)) {

  foreach ($services as $option) {
    // Some code
  }

}
```

Although I wouldn't worry too much. This is just a cleaner way of writing your code.